# Meaning of lag parameter in PST?

Tags: r, markov-chains, pst, traminer, sequence-analysis

In the `pmine()` function in `PST` you can use lags. What is this lag? Does it mean that it ignores the `lag` first positions in the sequence? Or does it mean that you allow for lags within the subsequences? From the documentation it is hard to understand what is actually meant by lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lag` parameter when searching patterns with the `pmine()` function means that we look only for patterns that are preceded by at least `lag` elements, i.e., for patterns with a context of length at least equal to `lag`.  The `lag` first positions will not belong to find patterns, but they could belong to their context. So, they are not ignored.

Comment: To clarify, is this then counted from the beginning of the sequence in the data? It is essentially a way of saying: "please don't consider the first `lag` states, unless they are part of the context of a pattern"?

Comment: Yes, you can say it this way. We could also say, 'look for patterns (filling the conditions) starting after the first lag positions.'